# How to tell when a DirectX fullscreen application is "minimized"

Tags: winapi, directx

I'm trying to monitor a DirectX application and "catch" it if it has been "minimized" for any reason (usually caused by a mis-behaving program stealing focus).

I figured using the [IsIconic function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527%28VS.85%29.aspx) would work, but it reports `false` when you ask it. Okay, so then I tried going with the [GetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, but it reports `SW_SHOWNORMAL`.

I guess it's technically not considered minimized by Windows. So then my question is, what is the correct way to detect (from a difference process) that a fullscreen DirectX application isn't running fullscreen in the foreground?

Comment: What version of Windows are you targeting/using? What version of Direct3D?

Comment: It would be nice if the solution was generic rather than specific, but if it has to be specific, the current target is Windows 7 with D3D9, though I expect we will target Windows 8/10 in the near future, and also probably a higher D3D version.

Comment: I ask because full-screen behavior was a bit different on Windows XP than it is on Windows Vista or later which uses DXGI to handle all that business--plus there's a Desktop Windows Manager running in the mix. There may also be some weirdness at work for you because by using legacy Direct3D 9 you are going to get a lot of 'appcompt' behavior trying to emulate the old Windows XP behavior. Anyhow, have you looked at ``WM_ACTIVATEAPP``?